# How to get a nested data from json using axios?

Tags: json, axios, datatable, nested, quasar-framework

A newbie here, I'm trying to use Quasar and Axios to make a simple user management system, and the problem is that I can't get the nested data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users (specificaly from the "address", "geo" and "company") and display it on my table.

I've tried looking up on various websites to get it working but none is working.

Sample from the link:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
```

Here is my code:

```
<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  setup() {
    let rows = ref([]);
    let columns = ref([
      {
        name: "id",
        label: "ID",
        align: "left",
        field: "id",
      },
      {
        name: "name",
        label: "Name",
        align: "left",
        field: "name",
      },
      {
        name: "username",
        label: "User Name",
        align: "left",
        field: "username",
      },
      {
        name: "email",
        label: "Email",
        align: "left",
        field: "email",
      },
      {
        name: "address",
        label: "Address",
        align: "left",
        field: "address",
      },
      {
        name: "phone",
        label: "Phone",
        align: "left",
        field: "phone",
      },
      {
        name: "website",
        label: "Website",
        align: "left",
        field: "website",
      },
      {
        name: "company",
        label: "Copany",
        align: "left",
        field: "company",
      },
    ]);

    const getUsers = () => {
      axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        .then((response) => {
          rows.value = response.data;
        });
    };

    getUsers();

    return { rows, columns };
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <q-page class="q-ma-xl">
    <q-table title="Todos" :rows="rows" :columns="columns" row-key="name" />
  </q-page>
</template>
```